# Stored Procedure populating a Model in .net Core

Tags: html, .net, .net-core

I have a project that has a login screen. When the user logs in the Controller calls another Class that I am using as a data Access class. This Class called the stored procedure to verify if the user is valid and pulls back all the user information and loads it into a UserModel. This works as I just have the data access method return a bool. So then I am logged in. But the information is not staying or is never stored in my model. I have been researching this and working off and on for this for weeks. I am hoping another set of eyes will help show me what I am missing. Thanks.

Here is my Model

```
public class UserModel
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Holds the current username.
        /// </summary>
        public string UserName {get;set;}

        /// <summary>
        /// Holds the First Name of the user.
        /// </summary>
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Holds the last name of the user.
        /// </summary>
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Holds the users Date of Birth.
        /// </summary>
        public string UserDOB { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Holds the users Email Address 
        /// that was provided.
        /// </summary>
        public string Email { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Holds the current Password of the user.
        /// </summary>
        public string Password { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Holds the Date the account was created.
        /// </summary>
        public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Holds the PK of the type of user,
        /// Admin, Standard, Promotional
        /// </summary>
        public int UserType { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is my Data Access

```
public bool UserLogin(string userName, string Password)
        {
            bool userFound = false;

            const string Query = @"GetUserLogin";

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(Query, connection)
                {
                    CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                };
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", userName);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Password);

                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    reader.Read();
                    userModel.UserName = reader["UserName"].ToString();
                    userModel.FirstName = reader["FirstName"].ToString();
                    userModel.LastName = reader["LastName"].ToString();
                    userModel.Email = reader["Email"].ToString();
                    userModel.UserDOB = reader["UserDOB"].ToString();

                    if (reader == null)
                    {
                        userFound = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        userFound = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            return userFound;
        }
```

This is my User Controller

```
    public class UserController : Controller
    {
        private UserLoginDataAccess dataAccess = new UserLoginDataAccess();

        // GET: /Login/
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Login(UserModel model)
        {
            bool isLoggedIn;

            isLoggedIn = dataAccess.UserLogin(model.UserName, model.Password);

            if (isLoggedIn)
            {
                return View("Dashboard");
            }
            else
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you verified the stored procedure, say in SQL Studio?

Comment: @RamblinRose Yes the stored Procedure is correctly sending the Data back. I have verified this in Debug. Thank you

Comment: `userFound = reader.Read()` should be enough.  Where is `userModel` defined? I see it as a parameter to `Login` but not defined in 'Data Access'. What do you see in the debugger?

Comment: Well I have tried Multiple ways to define userModel 
I have tried to pass it through as a parameter and I have also tried to just new it up in the class level. 
private UserModel userModel = new UserModel();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, this is never not null:

```cs
if (reader == null)
```

Secondly: where / how is `userModel` defined? If that is a field on the controller, then note that it jsn't persisted anywhere between requests. You need to use other approaches here. Usually an auth cookie of some kind.

Thirdly: I'm horrified to know whether you're doing a flat password compare in the DB; please let it be hashed...

Fourthly: writing your own security code is almost never a good idea. There are login providers that get it right. I recommend using them.

Fifthly: you should test whether `Read()` returned `true` or not - although frankly I think I'd recommend offloading all of this DB code to something like Dapper.

Comment: Hello Marc, I am in very early stages of this project and currently I do not have the passwords Hashed but that will be my next step.
But I will look into using Dapper and login providers. thank you very much!